# LowLevel Query Using Mongodb official C# Driver

Tags: mongodb, nosql

iam newbie on NoSQL
i need to query my database on lowest level without any overhead !

my application haven't any Entity Classes
all DataObject Parse and Create Dynamically on Json interface

now i want to know how can i talk to database server directly without any type conversion , parsing , ..
i need to querying like mongo console 
send Json to database and retrieving data on Json Format .

i need something like SqlDataReader , and SqlCommand 
Please Let me know how can i do this

Comment: Data is passed back and forth in BSON format, not JSON. So you'll have to do at least these two conversions. And why would you want to do that? There are bigger performance improvements in other places of your app.

Comment: Dear Sergio , can you provide me sample code of Bson Query ?